# Get inner most regex match for a href regex catcher

Tags: swift, regex

I want to catch `href` tags with a youtube link inside them.

I have this regex:

```
"<a.*?href=(.*?youtu.?be.*?)>.*?</a>"
```

It works but it doesn't stop if the tag is closed.

Meaning if I have:

```
<a href=www.google.come>google</a> <a href=www.youtube.com>youtube</a>
```

Desired result:

```
<a href=www.youtube.com>youtube</a
```

Actual result:

```
<a href=www.google.come>google</a> <a href=www.youtube.com>youtube</a>
```

It catches the whole thing, recognizing Googles `<a` as the opener and youtubes `</a>` as the closer.

I want to make my regex a little smarter so it knows how to stop the match when the the Google closer appeared, and start a new match attempt when the Youtube opener appears.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
"<a.*?[^>]href=(.*?youtu.?be.*?)>.*?</a>"
```

And also tried this:

```
"<a[^>].*?href=(.*?youtu.?be.*?)>.*?</a>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this pattern :

```
"<a[^>]*?href=[^>]*?youtu.?be[^>]*?>[^>]*?<\/a>"
```